# Attempting to check if the selected ID by the user has already been chosen in Java program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project that basically allows the user to create students, classes, edit them, etc. I am trying to assign ID to each student that the user creates, right now I am allowing the user to enter their own ID and the program would compare it with the other IDs, if the ID has not been selected yet, done but if it has been selected already, would display a message saying that it has been selected, please select a different ID but I am stuck in this part, here is the code I have, for simplify purposes I am only showing the main and create student methods, I will put // comments with what my idea was and hopefully you guys can assist me with some ideas, please look at the CreateStudent() method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class MidTermProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Here is the sample of menu choices for Main Menu.");
        
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to University Enrollment" + "\n1. Create Student" +
                            "\n2. Create Course" + "\n3. Create Enrollment" + "\n4. Edit Student" + "\n5. Edit Course"
                            + "\n6. Edit Enrollment" + "\n7. Display Student" + "\n8. Display Course" + "\n9. Display Enrollment"
                            + "\n10. Grades Sub Menu" + "\n0. --- Quit ---");
        
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice(1-10, 0 to Quit) :");
        int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if(userInput == 1) {
            CreateStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 2) {
            CreateCourse();
        } else if(userInput == 3) {
            CreateEnrollment();
        } else if(userInput == 4 ) {
            EditStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 5) {
            EditCourse();
        } else if(userInput == 6) {
            EditEnrollment();
        } else if(userInput == 7) {
            DisplayStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 8) {
            DisplayCourse();
        } else if(userInput == 9) {
            DisplayEnrollment();
        } else if(userInput == 10) {
            GradesSubMenu();
        } else if(userInput == 0) {
            System.out.print("Done");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Option, Please try again.");
            userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(userInput == 1) {
                CreateStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 2) {
                CreateCourse();
            } else if(userInput == 3) {
                CreateEnrollment();
            } else if(userInput == 4 ) {
                EditStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 5) {
                EditCourse();
            } else if(userInput == 6) {
                EditEnrollment();
            } else if(userInput == 7) {
                DisplayStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 8) {
                DisplayCourse();
            } else if(userInput == 9) {
                DisplayEnrollment();
            } else if(userInput == 10) {
                GradesSubMenu();
            } else if(userInput == 0) {
                System.out.print("Done");
            }
        }

    }
    
    public static void CreateStudent() throws IOException {
        String FullName;
        String address;
        String city;
        String state;
        int newStudentID;
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        
        //Create a Scanner Object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Open the file for write
        FileOutputStream fstream =
                new FileOutputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        DataOutputStream outputFile =
                new DataOutputStream(fstream);
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
        FullName = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(FullName);
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(address);
        
        System.out.print("City: ");
        city = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(city);
        
        System.out.print("State: ");
        state = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(state);
        
        //Asks the user to enter their own ID
        System.out.print("Please get a Student ID(1-10): ");
        newStudentID = keyboard.nextInt();
        outputFile.writeInt(newStudentID);
        
        //Once all data is completed, close the file.
        outputFile.close();
        
        //Open the file for reading.
        FileInputStream team = new FileInputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(team);
        
        //My idea here was to create a for loop to iterate through the file
//to find the already selected IDs, if any of the IDs matches the ID selected by the user 
//then a message will be display to select a different ID, if no match, then done will be displayed.
        
        System.out.print("\ndone");
        
        inputFile.close();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [consistent coding style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).  Classes start with a capital letter; variable names begin with lower case.  Both use camel case.

Like most beginners, you're writing too much code.  You are too worried about screen I/O.

If you've learned about Java collections I'd recommend that you create `CourseCatalog` and `StudentRoster` classes to hold the classes and students as they are created.

The `StudentRoster` would make it easy to determine if a student id already existed:

```
public class StudentRoster {

    private static int ID = 1;
    
    private Map<Integer, Student> roster = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addStudent(int id, Student s) { this.roster.put(id, student); }

    public void addStudent(Student s) { this.roster.put(ID++, student); }

    public boolean hasId(int id) { return this.roster.containsKey(id); }

    public Student getStudent(int id) { return this.roster.get(id); }

}
```

Comment: I am currently a software developer with Python and React but trying to learn Java, the course I joined isn't great and there is not a lot of help, we are learning based on the book starting out with java from control structures through data structures 4th edition. We haven't gotten to that StudentRoster

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you will need to store your IDs in a Set and check if you have already added this ID.
The easiest approach would be read your output file at the start of your programm and save all the IDs into a HashSet: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashset.asp
Then when a new ID gets entered, you need to check if the ID is already in the HashSet.
If the ID is there, you print an Error, else you add the student to your file and add the ID to the HashSet.

And just a tip, you shouldn't use the following code:

```
if(userInput == 1) {
    CreateStudent();
} else if(userInput == 2) {
    CreateCourse();
} else if(userInput == 3) {
    CreateEnrollment();
} else if(userInput == 4 ) {
    EditStudent();
} else if(userInput == 5) {
   EditCourse();
} else if(userInput == 6) {
    EditEnrollment();
} else if(userInput == 7) {
    DisplayStudent();
} else if(userInput == 8) {
    DisplayCourse();
} else if(userInput == 9) {
    DisplayEnrollment();
} else if(userInput == 10) {
    GradesSubMenu();
} else if(userInput == 0) {
     System.out.print("Done");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Option, Please try again.");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(userInput == 1) {
    ...
```

use something like this instead:

```
int userInput = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice(1-10, 0 to Quit) :");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(userInput == 1) {
        CreateStudent();
    } else if(userInput == 2) {
        CreateCourse();
    } else if(userInput == 3) {
        CreateEnrollment();
    } else if(userInput == 4 ) {
        EditStudent();
    } else if(userInput == 5) {
       EditCourse();
    } else if(userInput == 6) {
        EditEnrollment();
    } else if(userInput == 7) {
        DisplayStudent();
    } else if(userInput == 8) {
        DisplayCourse();
    } else if(userInput == 9) {
        DisplayEnrollment();
    } else if(userInput == 10) {
        GradesSubMenu();
    }
} while (userInput != 0);
```

This of course also isn't the best way, but I guess you are just a beginner, so don't go too deep and try to get your project to work in your way.

Comment: Thank you! that looks very helpful, will give a shot with the hash set, just starting on this Java world